# pubsub.NewClient method stuck on GKE golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing a golang app that uses Google Pub/Sub client library. I am using Google container engine for deployment. I followed the following steps for deployment -

1. Build golang binary using `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o bin/app app.go`
2. Build a docker image using dockerfile shown below.
3. Create kubernetes deployment.

Dockerfile -

```
FROM scratch 
ADD bin/app /
CMD ["/app"]
```

The app starts fine and I can see some initial debug logs. However, when I try to instantiate a pub/sub client using `client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectId)`, the method call never returns. I do not see the log message printed right after this statement.

I have "Cloud Pub/Sub" permission enabled on my GKE cluster. Also, the app runs without any issues on my local machine.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Never returns ?  No err ?

Comment: @MIkCode Yes the function never returns. If I write `fmt.Println("here")` right after that line, "here" never prints. No err.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I finally found the problem and its solution. My image does not contain any SSL certificates which are required for the pub/sub client (and many other libraries of course) to communicate.

Adding my local machine's `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file to the docker image's `/etc/ssl/certs/` location solved the problem.

This awesome [post](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/) at codeship is where I learned this solution.

Comment: Thanks you so much for figuring this out - saved me hours!