# pubsub.NewClient is stuck in development machine as well as in docker

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I understand, a similar issue has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618942/pubsub-newclient-method-stuck-on-gke-golang)

However suggested solution doesn't work for me.

Below is my code snippet

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("pubsub.NewClient: %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("pubsub newclient called")
defer client.Close()
```

However it get stuck in NewClient call and doesn't even return any error also.

Setting GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL to info shows below information.

```
INFO: 2019/12/07 07:46:14 parsed scheme: ""
INFO: 2019/12/07 07:46:14 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
INFO: 2019/12/07 07:46:14 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{pubsub.googleapis.com:443 0  <nil>}] }
INFO: 2019/12/07 07:46:14 balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: [{pubsub.googleapis.com:443 0} {pubsub.googleapis.com:443 1} {pubsub.googleapis.com:443 2} {pubsub.googleapis.com:443 3}]
```

I am running this program in ubuntu 16.04 and it contains proper ssl certs.

This same code doesn't run in docker too. 
Below is my docker file.

```
FROM golang:1.12 as builder
RUN mkdir /app
ADD main.go /app/
COPY go.mod go.sum /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .


FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
RUN ls -l
CMD ["./main"]
```

Can somebody suggest how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxy settings or something that could prevent to do the call to google? Might have something to do with this https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1202